# Handling multiple i2c_clients in one driver module (with sysfs)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, i2c

I want to create a kernel driver for tmp102 temperature sensors.
In one project I have only 1 sensor, in the other - 2 sensors. I want my kernel module to be able to support N sensors, not a fixed number. I have a problem with managing more than 1 struct i2c_client and creating sysfs entries for each of them. Here's how I'm doing it:

1. In the `probe()` function I get `struct i2c_client*` for each of the devices that I provide `I2C_BOARD_INFO()` for.
2. I then `kobject_create_and_add("tmp102", kernel_kobj)` to get the main directory for the modules in *sysfs*.
3. For each device I'm creating `sysfs_create_group()` which gets the pointer to statically created attributes. The attributes have the `(*show)()` and `(*store)()` pointers set to static functions, e.g.

   ```
   static ssize_t tmp102_sysfs_thigh_get_one(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, char *buf)
   ```

In this function I want to read via I2C. The problem is... I don't know how to get the `struct i2c_client *` for the device which should be somehow linked to this *sysfs* entry, and the I2C address is there!

How should I properly "link" i2c_client with *sysfs* entries, so that I can get the I2C address inside the functions?

Ideally, I would like to have just one set of functions (one for each of the attributes). The *sysfs* tree should look like that:

```
  /sysfs/kernel/tmp102
  |
  |-> <hex i2c address, e.g. /48>
  |   |
  |   |-> temperature   
  |
  |   
  |-> /49
      |
      |-> temperature
```

I want both 'temperature' attributes to use the same function, which is able to determine the I2C address, to which it should write.

Or maybe my architecture is plain wrong? If so, how should it look like for a driver that needs to handle multiple `i2c_client`s?

EDIT:

I decided to use `struct device_attribute` instead of regular `attribute`s. To my understanding, it is not easy to get the `struct device` pointer when using the regular attributes, same with `struct i2c_client`. They are not easily "linked" with `kobject`s from `/sys/kernel`, where I need to have my attributes for this project. `device_attribute`s can be found in `/sys/devices` - I used `sysfs_create_group` and linked my device's `kobject` with the `device_attribute` group. I used `sysfs_create_link`, and linked my device's `kobject` with the `/sys/kernel/tmp102`. This way I could create a folder (link) for each of the devices, which points to the original attributes folder in `/sys/devices`.

Comment: Creating and filling board info inside the drivers is against the model used in  Linux kernel. You need to create an agnostic (to the address) driver and provide a separate source of board information which would be ACPI, Device Tree, or legacy platform data.

Comment: I don't understand, the I2C_BOARD_INFO is not in the driver. It is in a patch applied to the kernel before the build process. This kernel does not yet support Device Tree. The module itself is address agnostic. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Seems I misread your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should know that there is already a kernel driver for the tmp102 that has a sysfs interface. Have a look at [drivers/hwmon/tmp102.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/drivers/hwmon/tmp102.c).

Now, for your issue, you have a `struct kobject` that is passed to you sysfs callback. You can call `kobj_to_dev()` to get a pointer to the device. Then, for example, you could use `dev_get_drvdata()` to get a pointer to your own private structure that would contain a pointer to the i2c client. Don't forget to set it first with `dev_set_drvdata()` in your probe.

You have can find an example in [drivers/rtc/rtc-ds1343.c](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/drivers/rtc/rtc-ds1343.c#L156) but it is using an spi_driver.

Comment: The problem is I can't use `kobj_to_dev()`, because the main kobj's parent is `kernel_kobj`. I want the folder to reside in `/sys/kernel/tmp102`. Now every device would create its own folder, for client with address `0x48` the folder would be `48`. This kobj's parent will be the `tmp102` kobj. So now this `struct kobject` which is passed to my sysfs `(*show)()` function isn't corelated with the device kobj. I don't know how to arrange the `struct kobjects` so that I can get access to the device kobj from `/sys/kernel/tmp102/`

Comment: On second thought - maybe I should just use the `device_attribute` instead of plain one and plug the attributes group to the `kernel_kobj`? I would get access to the device pointer, and then use either `dev_get_drvdata()` or `to_i2c_client()`? I will check this approach once I get the board back.